# Multiple variables in SciPy's optimize.minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, scipy, mathematical-optimization

According to the [SciPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), it is possible to minimize functions with multiple variables, yet it doesn't say how to optimize such functions.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from math import *

def f(c):
  return sqrt((sin(pi/2) + sin(0) + sin(c) - 2)**2 + (cos(pi/2) + cos(0) + cos(c) - 1)**2)

print(minimize(f, 3.14/2 + 3.14/7))
```

The above code try to minimize the function `f`, but for my task I need to minimize with respect to three variables.

Simply introducing a second argument and adjusting `minimize` accordingly yields an error:

```
TypeError: f() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**How does `minimize` work when minimizing with multiple variables?**

Comment: your code shows one scalar decision variable `c`. There is no indication of the other two decision variables, meaning this is not the multivariate function you want to solve. you want to optimize for three decision variables instead, for a function not shown, with each variable being scalar as well, `a`, `b`, `c`? Do you have an example of 2 *vectors* for decision variables instead? For example, `x` and `y` are two decision vectors/arrays, instead of scalars

Comment: @develarist I think it would be better to make a separate question for what you are asking. But, if you need to optimize two vectors, I would consider each element of the vector to be a variable to be optimized. So if you have two 3-element vectors, you have 6 variables to optimize.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Pack the multiple variables into a single array:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def f(params):
    # print(params)  # <-- you'll see that params is a NumPy array
    a, b, c = params # <-- for readability you may wish to assign names to the component variables
    return a**2 + b**2 + c**2

initial_guess = [1, 1, 1]
result = optimize.minimize(f, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

yields

```
[ -1.66705302e-08  -1.66705302e-08  -1.66705302e-08]
```

Comment: `print(params)` shows the array, but what are they? I see no input `params` being sent to the function `f` in the call to the function in the first place. and how do the `params` correspond to the function being optimized? Why are the three resulting elements identical (`-1.66705302e-08`). Instead of multiple *scalar* decision variables, how to optimize for multiple *vector* decision variables instead?

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.optimize.minimize` takes two mandatory arguments: the objective function and the initial guess of the variables of the objective function (so `len(initial)==len(variables)` has to be true). As it's an iterative algorithm, it requires an initial guess for the variables in order to converge. So the initial guess has to be an educated guess, otherwise the algorithm may not converge and/or the results would be incorrect.

Also, if the objective function uses any extra arguments (e.g. coefficients of the objective function), they cannot be passed as kwargs but has to be passed via the `args=` argument of `minimize` (which admits an array-like).

Since the OP doesn't have a multi-variable objective function, let's use a common problem: [least squares minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares).

The optimization problem solves for values where the objective function attains its minimum value. As [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670414/19123103) explained, they must be passed as a single object (`variables` in the function below) to the objective function. As mentioned before, we must pass an educated guess for these variables in order for the algorithm to converge.

```py
def obj_func(variables, coefs):
    gap = coefs[:, 0] - (variables * coefs[:, 1:]).sum(axis=1)
    return (gap**2).sum()

initial = [0, 0]
coefs = np.array([[0.4, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [5, 1, 2], [7, 1, 3], [8, 1, 4], [11, 1, 5], [13, 1, 6], [14, 1, 7], [16, 1, 8], [19, 1, 9]])
result = minimize(obj_func, initial, args=coefs)

minimizers = result.x         # [0.50181826, 2.00848483]
minimum = result.fun          # 2.23806060606064
```

As least squares minimization is how OLS regression coefficients are calculated, you can verify that the above indeed computes it by the following:

```py
from statsmodels.api import OLS
ols_coefs = OLS(coefs[:, 0], coefs[:, 1:]).fit().params
np.allclose(ols_coefs, minimizers)                         # True
```