# Utilizing scipy.optimize.minimize with multiple variables of different shapes

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimization

I am curious is there is a straightforward method for utilizing [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize) with multiple variables that take different shapes. For example, let's take a look at a matrix decomposition problem.

I apologize, but I will be using latex here in the hope that one day SO will implement it.

We can deconstruct the matrix $ A_{n \times m} $ into two matrices $ W_{k \times n} $ and $ H_{k \times m} s.t. A \approx W^TH $

There are numerous methods for solving for `W` and `H`, but let this just serve as an example problem.

We could solve this problem with `scipy.optimize.minimize` by first defining a cost function, and perhaps the first and second derivatives of that function, then initializing `W` and `H` and using `minimize` to calculate the values of `W` and `H` that minimize the function. Let's do that:

```
def f(x, *args):
    A, w_shape, w_size, h_shape = args
    W = x[:w_size].reshape(w_shape)
    H = x[w_size:].reshape(h_shape)
    sse = 0.5 * np.sum((A - W.T.dot(H))**2)
    return sse

def f_prime(x, *args):
    A, w_shape, w_size, h_shape = args
    W = x[:w_size].reshape(w_shape)
    H = x[w_size:].reshape(h_shape)
    gw = H.dot(H.T).dot(W) - H.dot(A.T)
    gh = W.dot(W.T).dot(H) - W.dot(A)
    return np.concatenate([gw.flatten(), gh.flatten()])

A = np.array([13, 18, 17, 24, 21, 30]).reshape(3,2)
W = np.random.rand(2,3)
H = np.random.rand(2,2)
x0 = np.concatenate([W.flatten(), H.flatten()])
out = so.minimize(f, x0, args=(A, W.shape, W.size, H.shape), jac=f_prime, method='BFGS')
print(out['fun'])
2.0172245004128515e-12
```

So from the output of the minimize function it looks like we successfully calculated a `W` and `H` that approximates `A` (quite well). We can check the reconstruction as well.

```
Wf = out['x'][:W.size].reshape(W.shape)
Hf = out['x'][W.size:].reshape(H.shape)
print(Wf.T.dot(Hf))
array([[ 13.00000041,  18.00000054],
       [ 17.00000062,  23.99999976],
       [ 21.00000084,  29.99999844]]
```

Great! But as you can see I implemented some tricks for passing a single flattened array into the `x0` argument and then split it up into `W` and `H` within each function. This example is pretty simple, but in more complex problems this can get a little annoying/ugly. Moreover, it feels hacky.

There is documentation for using `minimize` for multiple variables (see [Scipy lecture notes: 2.7. Mathematical optimization: finding minima of functions](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/mathematical_optimization/#conjugate-gradient-descent)), just not with multiple arrays of different shapes. There are also SO questions along this line like [Multiple variables in SciPy's optimize.minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize), but again no mention of the variable being arrays.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is a more elegant method for passing multiple arrays as arguments to `minimize`. Something akin to:

```
minimize(f, [W.flatten(), H.flatten()], jac=f_prime, args=...)
```

Which doesn't work, but seems much more straightforward.