# Scipy.optimize.minimize objective function ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am using scipy.optimize.minimize for a small optimization problem with 9 free variables. My objective function is basically a wrapper around another function, and if I evaluate my objective function, the return type is 'numpy.float32'... which is a scalar? However, I am getting the following error when attempting to use the minimize function:

```
raise ValueError("Objective function must return a scalar")
ValueError: Objective function must return a scalar
```

Is it not possible to wrap the objective function around another function? The other function arguments are globally declared, but if this is not ok, I can hardcode them into the beam_shear function.

Relevant code snippets:

```
from numpy import array, shape, newaxis, isnan, arange, zeros, dot, linspace
from numpy import pi, cross, tile, arccos,sin, cos, sum, atleast_2d, asarray, float32, ones

from numpy import sum, reshape
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def normrow(A):
    A = atleast_2d(asarray(A, dtype=float32))
    return (sum(A ** 2, axis=1) ** 0.5).reshape((-1, 1))

def beam_shear(xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, x):

    # will not work for overlapping nodes...
    s         = zeros((len(xyz), 3))
    xyz_pt0   = xyz[pt0, :]
    xyz_pt1   = xyz[pt1, :]
    xyz_pt2   = xyz[pt2, :]
    e01       = xyz_pt1 - xyz_pt0
    e12       = xyz_pt2 - xyz_pt1
    e02       = xyz_pt2 - xyz_pt0
    trip_norm = cross(e01, e12)
    mu        = 0.5 * (xyz_pt2 - xyz_pt1)
    l01       = normrow(e01)
    l12       = normrow(e12)
    l02       = normrow(e02)
    l_tn      = normrow(trip_norm)
    l_mu      = normrow(mu)
    a         = arccos((l01**2 + l12**2 - l02**2) / (2 * l01 * l12))
    k         = 2 * sin(a) / l02 # discrete curvature
    ex        = trip_norm / tile(l_tn, (1, 3))
    ez        = mu / tile(l_mu, (1, 3))
    ey        = cross(ez, ex)
    kb        = tile(k / l_tn, (1, 3)) * trip_norm
    kx        = tile(sum(kb * ex, 1)[:, newaxis], (1, 3)) * ex
    m         = x * kx
    cma       = cross(m, e01)
    cmb       = cross(m, e12)
    ua        = cma / tile(normrow(cma), (1, 3))
    ub        = cmb / tile(normrow(cmb), (1, 3))
    c1        = cross(e01, ua)
    c2        = cross(e12, ub)
    l_c1      = normrow(c1)
    l_c2      = normrow(c2)
    ms        = sum(m**2, 1)[:, newaxis]
    Sa        = ua * tile(ms * l_c1 / (l01 * sum(m * c1, 1)[:, newaxis]), (1, 3))
    Sb        = ub * tile(ms * l_c2 / (l12 * sum(m * c2, 1)[:, newaxis]), (1, 3))
    Sa[isnan(Sa)] = 0
    Sb[isnan(Sb)] = 0
    s[pt0, :] += Sa
    s[pt1, :] -= Sa + Sb
    s[pt2, :] += Sb
    return s

def cross_section_obj(x):
    s = beam_shear(xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, x)
    l_s = normrow(s)
    val = sum(l_s)
    return val

xyz = array([[ 0, 0., 0.],
        [ 0.16179067,  0.24172157,  0.],
        [ 0.33933063,  0.47210142,  0.],
        [ 0.53460629,  0.68761389,  0.],
        [ 0.75000537,  0.88293512, 0.],
        [ 0.98816469,  1.04956383, 0.],
        [ 1.25096091,  1.17319961,  0.],
        [ 1.5352774,  1.22977204,  0.],
        [ 1.82109752,  1.18695051,  0.],
        [ 2.06513705, 1.03245579,  0.],
        [ 2.23725517,  0.79943842,  0.]])

pt0 = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
pt1 = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
pt2 = array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
EIx = (ones(len(pt1)) * 12.75).reshape(-1, 1)

bounds = []
for i in range(len(EIx)):
    bounds.append((EIx[i][0], EIx[i][0] * 100))


print(type(cross_section_obj(EIx)))
res = minimize(cross_section_obj, EIx, method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds)
```

As mentioned before:

```
print(type(cross_section_obj(EIx)))
```

returns:

```
<type 'numpy.float32'>
```

EIx is the set of initial values for the optimization, which is an array of shape (9, 1).

Comment: there is a parenthesis missing at the start of `sum` which is assigned to `l_s`. additionally you don't need to reshape if you're just going to sum to a scalar

Comment: Add an example we can run. Yes... the shapes might be a problem. For debugging: add ```print(type(val))``` in the line before ```return val```.

Comment: Also: ```10 free variables``` != ```EIx is the set of initial values for the optimization, which is an array of shape (9, 1).```

Comment: Here's an example, hope this clarifies things somewhat! You were also right about the free variables (should be 9 for this case), and the sum parentheses have been fixed.

Comment: That code has even an error in beam_shear (which we don't know). Impossible to work on the problems with scipy then. And you still did not do my debugging-recommendation (maybe you think it's covered by your print; it's not! at least not in general).

Comment: I tested your debugging suggestion, and it also returns `<type 'numpy.float32'>.` Beam shear works as I expected, I'm using this snippet in several other situations.... Is the point that scipy cannot work with a function inside a function?

Comment: scipy does indeed work with a function inside a function just try this https://repl.it/MkJt/2

Comment: beam_shear throws an error (in the code above!), no discussion. That's enough for me that i can't debug it for you. I can imagine the overall problem, but touching it will (probably) break every other code of yours.

Comment: @sascha beam_shear does not throw an error for me, I have not edited it. version is python 3.6

Comment: numpy-version, scipy-version (1.13.1 / 0.19.0 here)?

Comment: scipy: 0.19.0, numpy: 1.12.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to look at [Utilizing scipy.optimize.minimize with multiple variables of different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867337/utilizing-scipy-optimize-minimize-with-multiple-variables-of-different-shapes). What is important to understand is that if you want to use minimize with arrays, you should pass in the flattened version and then reshape. For that reason I always include the desired shape as one of the arguments to the minimize function. In your case I would do something like so:

```
def cross_section_obj(x, *args):
    xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, shape = args
    x = x.reshape(shape)
    s = beam_shear(xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, x)
    l_s = normrow(s)
    val = sum(l_s)
    return val
```

Then your `minimize` call would change like so:

```
res = minimize(cross_section_obj, EIx.flatten(), method='SLSQP',
               bounds=bounds, args=(xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, EIx.shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `EIx` of parameter values is two-dimensional; it has shape (9,1). During the minimization process this array becomes one-dimensional after the first iteration. However, your function `beam_shear` does not work if `x` is one-dimensional.

You can fix this by changing `cross_section` to the following:

```
def cross_section_obj(x):
    x = x.reshape((-1,1))
    s = beam_shear(xyz, pt0, pt1, pt2, x)
    l_s = normrow(s)
    val = sum(l_s)
    return val
```

The code then runs, but of course you need to double-check if that is what you actually want to calculate.