# Multiple variables and arguments in SciPy's optimize.fmin

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I wish to use scipy's optimize.fmin function to find the minimum of a function, which is a function of both variables I wish to minimize over and parameters which do not change (are not optimized over).

I am able to do this when optimizing over a single variable here:

```
from scipy import optimize

c1=4
c2=-1

def f(x,c1,c2):
    return x**2+c1+c2

guess_f=1
minimum = optimize.fmin(f,guess_f,args=(c1,c2),maxfun=400,maxiter=400,ftol=1e-2,xtol=1e-4)
```

However, I cannot get this to work when I add another variable to minimize over:

```
def g(x,y,c1,c2):
    return x*y+c1+c2

guess_g=[1,1]

minimum2= optimize.fmin(g,guess_g,args=(c1,c2),maxfun=400,maxiter=400,ftol=1e-2,xtol=1e-4)
```

I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c2'
```

I did find [Multiple variables in SciPy's optimize.minimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize), and a solution is presented here in which the variables to be optimized over need to be grouped together as their own array. I try something like this below:

```
def g(params,c1,c2):
    x,y=params
#    print(params)
    return x*y+c1*x+c2

guess_g=[1,1]
minimum2= optimize.fmin(g,guess_g,args=(c1,c2),maxfun=4000,maxiter=4000,ftol=1e-2,xtol=1e-4)
```

I do not receive a TypeError, but what I do get is the "Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded." message along with a RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars after removing the cwd from sys.path. (additionally, I tried using the optimize.minimize command to do the same thing, but was unable to get it to work when adding the extra arguments, but I do not post that code here as the question is already getting long).

So this does not seem to be the correct way to do this.

How do I go about optimizing with optimize.fmin function over multiple variables, while also giving my function additional arguments?

Comment: *"So this does not seem to be the correct way to do this."*  It is the correct way.  The problem is that your objective function `g` does not have a minimum.  The graph of `x*y + c` is a [hyperbolic paraboloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicParaboloid.html).  Try changing `g` to, for example, `x**2 + y**2 + c1 + c2`.

Comment: yes, you are correct - apparently I wasn't thinking much about my function! Thanks, all is well now!