# How to minimize function like this

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming, minimize

Function:

```
def Phi(u, X):
    return -(1+u[0]*X[0]+u[1]*X[1]+u[2]*X[2]+u[3]*X[3])
```

And I know that `X[0]...X[3]` is in `[-0.08,0.08]` and `u[0],u[1],u[2],u[3] >= 0` and `u[0]+u[1]+u[2]+u[3] = 1`, also I know gradient of my functions. Then I defined constraint:

```
def constraint1(u):
    return u[0]+u[1]+u[2]+u[3]-1.0
def constraint2(u):
    return u[0]-1.0
def constraint3(u):
    return u[1]-1.0
def constraint4(u):
    return u[2]-1.0
def constraint5(u):
    return u[3]-1.0
```

And bounds

```
bnds = Bounds ([-0.08, -0.08, -0.08], [0.08, 0.08, 0.08])
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint2},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint3},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint4},
               {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint5},]
print(minimize(Phi, method='BFGS', jac=grad, constraints=cons, bounds=bnds))
```

But I have " `TypeError: minimize() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x0'` ". And I havent information about `x0`. Is it correct minimization of function with constraints or its impossible to do this?

UPD

Result is

```
def Phi2(params):
    u0,u1,u2,u3,x0,x1,x2,x3 = params
    return -(1+u0*x0+u1*x1+u2*x2+u3*x3)


x0 = np.asarray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

def constraint1(params):
    u0,u1,u2,u3,x0,x1,x2,x3 = params
    return u0+u1+u2+u3-1.0


bnds = Bounds ([0,0,0,0,-0.08,-0.08,-0.08,-0.08,], [1,1,1,1,0.08, 0.08, 0.08])

cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint1}]
print(minimize(Phi2,x0, method='BFGS', constraints=cons, bounds=bnds))
```

But there is some problem. I have gradient for u0,u1,u2,u3 in numpy array 'grad'. How to use it correctly? If i do jac=grad in parametrs of minimize then result is

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Also: BFGS does not support constraints. Consult the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) says that x0 it is a positional argument and so it is required.

It says this about x0:

> Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where ‘n’ is the number of independent variables.

It seems like you have to provide your initial guess at the minimum. Have you tried supplying an empty array?

Comment: When I add x0 (x0 = np.zeros(shape=(1,4))) to minimize, I have "TypeError: Phi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'"

Comment: Have you seen this example here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#nelder-mead-simplex-algorithm-method-nelder-mead

Comment: The reason it is failing is that scipy expects `Phi` to be a function like: `fun(x, *args)` where `*args` is a list of constants but in you have  `Phi(u, X)` where `X` is not constant.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that such a function cannot be minimized?

Comment: It should be possible, this article gives some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize I'll see I can make sense of it.

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot. But now I have little problem with gradient(updated post)

Comment: I don't understand the documentation for the constaints. When I provided this dummy function it worked: `grad = lambda x: np.zeros(shape=(1,4))`