# Multiple variables in Scipy.optimize minimize

Tags: python, scipy

My question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize) previously asked. I am trying to follow the answer.

```
def simulator(X,Y,Z):
    return X+Y+Z

def f(params):
   X,Y,Z = params 
   A = simulator(params)
   return A

bound = [(10,30), (10, 30), (10, 30)]
x0 = (10,10,10)
result = minimize(f,x0,bounds=bound)
```

I am getting error

```
simulator() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'Y' and 'Z'.
```

In real, simulator fx is far more complex but I am facing same issue as in this simplified code.

Comment: `A = simulator(X, Y, Z)` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted in comments,

```
A = simulator(X, Y, Z)
```