# Minimizing a function of two variables using scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization

I have written the following code in Python:

```
def f_multi_para(q_sq, alpha_par):
    return f_0 / (q_sq * alpha_par)

def dB_dqsq_model2_para(q_sq, V_ub_par, alpha_par):
    sec1 = G_F**2 * V_ub_par
    sec2 = (1 - m_e**2 / q_sq)**2
    sec3 = (q_sq * (1 + m_e**2 / q_sq) * f_multi_para(q_sq, alpha_par)**2)
    return sec1 * sec2 * sec3

def chi_sq(params):
    V_ub_par, alpha_par = params
    return np.sum(((dB_dqsq_arr - np.array([dB_dqsq_model2_para(v, V_ub_par, alpha_par) for v in q_sq_arr])) / dBdqsq_err_arr)**2)

initial_guess = [0.0037, 0.54]
result = optimize.minimize(chi_sq, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Where `q_sq`, `V_ub_par`, and `alpha_par` are the function parameters, and the rest are stored variables. I am trying to minimize `chi_sq(params)` with respect to the parameters `V_ub_par` and `alpha_par` whilst `q_sq` takes several values through a for loop. I found a solution to minimizing a multivariate function using `scipy.optimize` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670333/multiple-variables-in-scipys-optimize-minimize) and I followed the same methodology; however, when I run the code, the following error pops up:

```
ValueError: The user-provided objective function must return a scalar value.
```

I am not sure what this error means, and how to fix it (for context, I am relatively new to python, and programming in general).

I am using the following libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as optimize
```

And the variables in the above code are either integers or arrays, given as follows:

```
f_0 = 0.261
G_F = 1.166 * 10**(-5)
m_e = 0.511 * 10**(-3)
dB_dqsq_arr = np.array([7.2,7.14,6.7,7.56,6.44,7.17,6.67,6.33,6.2,4.32,4.25,3.4,1.17])
dBdqsq_err_arr = np.array([0.70,0.45,0.39,0.43,0.43,0.45,0.47,0.48,0.44,0.43,0.41,0.42,0.26])
q_sq_arr = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25])
```

Comment: can you provide all the imports and context for the modules. such as the origins of dB_dqsq_arr and m_e / f_0 / G_F

Comment: @TheCableGUI Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated my question with the libraries I have imported and the variables used.

Comment: if at all possible could you share the "q_sq_arr" variable as well?

Comment: @TheCableGUI my apologies for missing that out, I have now added q_sq_arr as well.

Comment: Is your objective function (chi_sq) returning a numpy array at the moment? (instead of a single float). If so, you will need to modify that function to return a float (hard to tell what your logic is with looping around dB_dqsq_model2_para - but perhaps you are missing a "sum" or other reduction afterwards)

Comment: @AzmyRajab Ah yes, I just realized that I missed the sum function, the chi_sq function is supposed to be a float which returns the sum of the mentioned function. I tried adding np.sum() around the current return value; however, now the following error shows: "ValueError: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss."

Comment: i posted the solution with the corrected functions and works as intended.

Comment: are you by chance calculating theoretical neutrino-nucleus interactions in particle physics using differential cross section scatting process with respect to squared momentum transfers?

Comment: @TheCableGUI No, I am tyring to extract V_ub and alpha information for B meson decays by comparing various form factor models and chi-square minimization. Though it might not be exactly evident from the code in my post  because I have removed several variables so as to not bombard the readers with too many unecessary variables which do not really affect the way the code itself works.

Comment: @noobanomaly right on. have fun. Is there any place i could start if i was interested in this?

Answer (score 0):

To further debug your code i constructed this analyzing function and scalar generic typing functions, use it to evalute your values to a further extent.

```py
from typing import Union, TypeVar
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import OptimizeResult


# Define a generic scalar type Scalar
scalar_types = (int, float, complex)
Scalar = TypeVar('Scalar', *scalar_types)


def scalar(value: Scalar) -> Union[Scalar, Exception]:
    """ construct a scalar using generic typing """

    if isinstance(value, scalar_types):
        return value
    
    elif isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
        raise Exception("Expected a scalar (int, complex, float) value but received np.ndarray")

    elif isinstance(value, OptimizeResult):
        raise Exception("Expected a scalar but got an scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult")

    try:
        print(dir(value))
    except:
        
        try:
            print(vars(value))
        except:
            print("dir and vars can not be used on ", type(value))
        
    return Exception(f"Expected a scalar (int, complex, float) value but received {type(value)}")
```

***SOLUTION***
Your function chi_sq does not return a scalar. it returns a np.ndarray. Rework the chi_sq to ensure that it returns a type of int, complex or float.

```py
def chi_sq(params):
    V_ub_par, alpha_par = params
    vals = (dB_dqsq_arr - np.array([dB_dqsq_model2_para(v, V_ub_par, alpha_par) for v in q_sq_arr]))
    chi = [x / dBdqsq_err_arr for x in vals]
    return np.sum(chi)
```

***Resulting Code***

```py
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import scipy.optimize as optimize


# DATA
f_0 = 0.261 # Double
G_F = 1.166 * 10**(-5) # Double
m_e = 0.511 * 10**(-3) # Double

# TYPE array[float]
dB_dqsq_arr = np.array([7.2,7.14,6.7,7.56,6.44,7.17,6.67,6.33,6.2,4.32,4.25,3.4,1.17])
# TYPE array[float]
dBdqsq_err_arr = np.array([0.70,0.45,0.39,0.43,0.43,0.45,0.47,0.48,0.44,0.43,0.41,0.42,0.26])
# TYPE array[int]
q_sq_arr = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25])



def f_multi_para(q_sq, alpha_par):
    return f_0 / (q_sq * alpha_par)

def dB_dqsq_model2_para(q_sq, V_ub_par, alpha_par):
    sec1 = G_F**2 * V_ub_par
    sec2 = (1 - m_e**2 / q_sq)**2
    sec3 = (q_sq * (1 + m_e**2 / q_sq) * f_multi_para(q_sq, alpha_par)**2)
    return sec1 * sec2 * sec3

def chi_sq(params):
    V_ub_par, alpha_par = params
    vals = (dB_dqsq_arr - np.array([dB_dqsq_model2_para(v, V_ub_par, alpha_par) for v in q_sq_arr]))
    chi = [x / dBdqsq_err_arr for x in vals]
    return np.sum(chi)


initial_guess = [0.0037, 0.54]
print(type(chi_sq(initial_guess)))
result = optimize.minimize(chi_sq, initial_guess)
if result.success:
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)
else:
    raise ValueError(result.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following fixes vectorisation gaps and runs successfully. It's suspicious that the minimum found is equal to the initial guess, but I consider that to be a separable problem.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

f_0 = 0.261
G_F = 1.166e-5
m_e = 0.511e-3
dB_dqsq_arr = np.array((7.2,7.14,6.7,7.56,6.44,7.17,6.67,6.33,6.2,4.32,4.25,3.4,1.17))
dBdqsq_err_arr = np.array((0.70,0.45,0.39,0.43,0.43,0.45,0.47,0.48,0.44,0.43,0.41,0.42,0.26))
q_sq_arr = np.arange(1, 26, 2)


def f_multi_para(q_sq: int | np.ndarray, alpha_par: float) -> float:
    return f_0 / (q_sq * alpha_par)


def dB_dqsq_model2_para(q_sq: int | np.ndarray, V_ub_par: float, alpha_par: float) -> float:
    sec1 = G_F**2 * V_ub_par
    sqdiff = 1 - m_e**2 / q_sq
    sec2 = sqdiff**2
    sec3 = q_sq * sqdiff * f_multi_para(q_sq, alpha_par)**2
    return sec1 * sec2 * sec3


def chi_sq(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    V_ub_par, alpha_par = params
    chi = (
        dB_dqsq_arr -
        dB_dqsq_model2_para(q_sq_arr, V_ub_par, alpha_par)
    ) / dBdqsq_err_arr
    return chi.dot(chi)


def regression_test() -> None:
    actual = chi_sq((0.004, 0.54))
    assert np.isclose(actual, 2307.989692506141, rtol=0, atol=1e-12)


def solve() -> None:
    initial_guess = (0.0037, 0.54)
    result = optimize.minimize(fun=chi_sq, x0=initial_guess)
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    fitted_params = result.x
    print(fitted_params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    regression_test()
    solve()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Regarding the initial values being equal to the minimizations, that is to be expected since the intial guesses that I choose are the literature values for the two quantities. I did this on purpose so as to not choose values which are too off from the literature values (because I wasn't sure what the conditions on setting the initial guess values are).